Conjugated centraliser in $\mathrm{GL}_2$
Let $E/F$ be a quadratic (unramified) extension of $p$-adic fields. Let $\sigma$ be the non-trivial conjugation of $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$. Let $G = \mathrm{GL}_2$.
Let $\delta \in G(E)$ such that $N \delta := \delta \sigma(\delta)$ is regular semisimple, that is, characteristic and minimal polynomial of $N \delta$ agree. Let $\gamma \in G(F)$ such that $\gamma$ is conjugate to $N \delta$. [This is possible since the characteristic polynomial of $N \delta$ is $\sigma$-invariant, so we may simply choose $\gamma$ with the same characteristic and minimal polynomial as $N \delta$.] Then $\gamma$ is regular semisimple.
Consider the centraliser
$$
G_{N \delta}(F) := G_\gamma(F) := \{h \in G(F) : h^{-1} \gamma h = \gamma\}
$$
and the twisted centraliser
$$
G_\delta^\sigma(E) := \{h \in G(E) : h^{-1} \delta \sigma(h) = \delta\}.
$$
I want to show that
$$
G_{N \delta}(F) \cong G_\delta^\sigma(E).
$$

I will just write $G_{N \delta}$ and $G_\delta^\sigma$ from now on.
My biggest problem is the change of fields in this group isomorphism.
I have found some relations. For all $u \in G(E)$, we have

$G_{u^{-1} \delta \sigma(u)} = u^{-1} G_\delta^\sigma u$,
$G_{\sigma(\delta)}^\sigma = \sigma(G_\delta^\sigma)$,
$G_{u^{-1} (N \delta) u} = u^{-1} G_{N \delta} u$,
$N(u^{-1} \delta \sigma(u)) = u^{-1} (N \delta) u$,
$\sigma(N \delta) = \delta^{-1} (N \delta) \delta$.

Moreover by definition, $G_\delta^\sigma$ is always contained in $C_{G(E)}(N \delta)$, the centralizer of $N \delta$ in $G(E)$ (which is not $G_{N \delta}$).
My advisor told me I could choose $\delta$ such that $N \delta \in G(F)$. This is because $u^{-1} (N \delta) u = \gamma$ for some $u \in G(E)$, and so $G_{N \delta} \cong G_{N(u^{-1} \delta u)}$ and $G_\delta^\sigma \cong G_{u^{-1} \delta \sigma(u)}$. So choose $u^{-1} \delta \sigma(u)$ for $\delta$.
But now I don't know how to continue.

This problem is motivated by defining the twisted orbital integral in context of base change for $G$ (base change fundamental lemma). This paper claims in sec. 3 that $G_\delta^\sigma$ is an inner form of $G_{N \delta}$, even for cyclic extensions $E/F$. This paper claims, right before Def. 1.0.1, that this also holds for certain classes of reductive groups $G$.

As it turned out, I only needed to continue reading the first paper. The proof idea is inspired by Prop.3.4. It crucially relies on the fact that for regular semisimple elements $x \in G(F)$, we have $G_x(F) \cong F[x]^\times$. Choose $\delta \in G(E)$ such that $\gamma := N \delta \in G(F)$ as stated in the post.

Show that $G_\delta^\sigma \subseteq G_\gamma$. We already know that $G_\delta^\sigma \subseteq C_{G(E)}(\gamma)$, so it remains to show that $G_\delta^\sigma \subseteq G(F)$. Let $x \in G_\delta^\sigma$, i.e. $\sigma(x) = \delta^{-1} x \delta$. We already know $x \in C_{G(E)}(\gamma)$. Since $\gamma = \sigma(\gamma) = \delta^{-1} \gamma \delta$, we have $\delta \in C_{G(E)}(\gamma)$ as well. Since $C_{G(E)}(\gamma) \cong E[\gamma]^\times$ is abelian, $x$ and $\delta$ commute, and so $x = \delta^{-1} x \delta = \sigma(x)$, i.e. $x \in G(F)$ as desired.
Show that $G_\gamma \subseteq G_\delta^\sigma$. Let $x \in G_\gamma$. Obviously $x \in C_{G(E)}(\gamma)$. We observed above that $\delta \in C_{G(E)}(\gamma)$. Since $C_{G(E)}(\gamma) \cong E[\gamma]^\times$ is abelian, $x$ commutes with $\delta$. It follows that $\sigma(x) = x = \delta^{-1} x \delta$, i.e. $x \in G_\delta^\sigma$ as desired.

